# Load a BMP in opengl visual cpp

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opengl

I need to apply a texture in a polygon. So I searched and I found many sources but i'm most of them I had problems in include and loading BMP picture.  (developing in visual cpp 10). So can anyone tell-me the easy way to load a BMP file and how to apply the texture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way is to use GDI+ class `Bitmap`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534420%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

You create an object with a constructor which takes a filename and then get a pointer to the buffer which contains the pixels using `LockBits()` method. That method gives you a pointer to a buffer which you can send to OpenGL texture functions.